# Про́жили или прожи́ли — как правильно?

Tags: орфоэпия

*Мы **про́жили** вместе тридцать лет* или *Мы **прожи́ли** вместе тридцать лет.*
Как правильно говорить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ударение на первом слоге.

**[Русское словесное ударение:](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)**

пр**о**жили

[Другой словарь](http://udarenie.gramatik.ru/prozhityj), вызывающий у меня меньшее доверие, рассказывает:

> про́жи́тый; кр. ф. про́жи́т, прожита́, про́жи́то; про́жил и прожи́л,
>   про́жило и прожило́, про́жили и прожи́ли; прожи́вший

Answer (score 3):

Предпочтительно: **про́жили**. Но и произношение с ударением на втором слоге не считается ошибкой.

См. ***Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф. Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. М., 2012***:

> **ПРОЖИ́ТЬ**, <…> **про́жили**   <…> *и допуст. младш.* **прожи́ли**…